# Is there any integration test framework for Ink contract?

Tags: ink

Same as title
Is there any integration test framework for Ink contract?

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at [Redspot](https://github.com/patractlabs/redspot), but it does not seem to be maintained anymore.
Generally, you can write integration tests using `polkadot.js`.